# Selenium / Java : Encountered "Exception in thread main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/Timer while executing Chromedriver step

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have basic  file and running the java file, throws No classDeffoundError: io/netty/util/Timer at

```
 packkage cucumber ;
public class seleniumTesting{
System.setproperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\downloads\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new Chromedriver();
```

please suggest where is the issue.

Comment: I'm possible to say with information you've provided. But I do reckon that you're missing quite a few transitive dependencies. Consider using Maven instead of downloading them by hand.

Comment: my organization don't allow to connect to mvn repo due to policies due to this i had to download by hand.

Comment: make sure you've got all the dependencies necessary added to your project.  Selenium itself will have a "lib" folder inside the zip which includes netty utils.  (not familiar with Cucumber or what libraries it includes... watch for duplicates as they will throw similar errors...)